# get webpacked module function variable

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

So, i have a function in file that converts into bundler.js via webpack (devtool: 'eval-source-map'):

```
function getTable(tname, trowid) {
  return get(ref(db, `table_name/${tname}/table_row_${String("0" + trowid).slice(-2)}`)).then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log(snapshot.val()); // need to return this value
    }
  });
}
window.getTable = getTable;
```

and i need call this function in main.js smt like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 69; i++) {
  document.getElementById(i).value = window.getTable(tname, i);
}
```

I'd tried simply return this vale, do it global variable and more, but in result i'm still getting "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of logging your value, return it to the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) your `getTable()` function is returning with `return snapshot.val()` :

```js
if (snapshot.exists()) {
  return snapshot.val();
}
```

This makes it so `getTable()` returns a Promise that fulfills with the value that `snapshot.val()` returns. Now you have a few options. One is to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) on each promise returned by the `getTable()` function to "extract" the value from the Promise:

```js
async function populateValues() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 69; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i).value = await getTable(tname, i);
  }
}
populateValues();
```

This will call each `getTable` function one at a time, perform the asynchronous operation/code within it, wait for that to complete (ie: wait for the Promise `getTable()` returns to fulfill with a value), then update your element's `.value`. Once done, it will proceed to the next iteration, and it will do this `69` times. For something faster, you can kick off all your calls to `getTable()` in parallel, and then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all of them have been fulfilled:

```js
async function populateValues() {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 69; i++) {
    promises.push(getTable(tname, i)); // kick off all your asynchronous calls (so that they run in parallel)
  }

  const tableValues = await Promise.all(promises); // wait for each async operation to finish, then iterate the data and update your UI
  for(const [i, val] of tableValuese.entries()) { // you can use a standard `for` loop here to iterate your `tableValues` array if you'd like
    document.getElementById(i).value = val;
  }
   
}
populateValues();
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, how i actually did not think about it